# Can i disable pct-encoding in OpenFeign for @RequestLine annotation?

Tags: feign, openfeign

I have a use case where URI comes from external source in the string format and is already pct-encoded.

I defined my interface like this:

```
    @RequestLine("GET {path}")
    String getMeStuff(@Param("path") String path);
```

But when `path` variable expands, it will be pct-encoded by Feign.
This results in "double encoding".

Is there a way to pass `path` variable `as is` to Http Request line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [approach suggested by @velo on OpenFeign Github issues](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/2238#issuecomment-1819273356)

```
@RequestLine("GET")
String getMeStuff(URI uri);
```